# Не отправляется сообщение из формы обратной связи на сайте, нажимаю отправить и выходит пуустая белая страница

Tags: javascript, php, форма

есть форма обратной связи, но данные почему-то не отправляются на почту. Нажимаю кнопку отправить, перенаправляется на contact_process.php и выходит пустая страница.
Не могу понять в чем проблема. Пожалуйста, помогите.

1 код обратной связи

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
                <form class="row contact_form" action="contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Enter Subject">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="1" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="primary-btn text-uppercase">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2 contact_process.php

```
<?php

$to = "manager@belgorodtour.ru";
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$number = $_REQUEST['number'];
$cmessage = $_REQUEST['message'];

$headers = "From: $from";
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$subject = "Your message has been received.";

$logo = 'img/logo.png';
$link = '#';

$body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Message</title></head><body>";
$body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
$body .= "<thead style='text-align: center;'><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>";
$body .= "<a href='{$link}'><img src='{$logo}' alt=''></a><br><br>";
$body .= "</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
$body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Name:</strong> {$name}</td>";
$body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td>";
$body .= "</tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Subject:</strong> {$csubject}</td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='border:none;'>{$cmessage}</td></tr>";
$body .= "</tbody></table>";
$body .= "</body></html>";

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

?>

3 mail-script.js

```
    // -------   Mail Send ajax

 $(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#myForm'); // contact form
    var submit = $('.submit-btn'); // submit button
    var alert = $('.alert-msg'); // alert div for show alert message

    // form submit event
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

        $.ajax({
            url: 'mail.php', // form action url
            type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
            dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
            data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert.fadeOut();
                submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
                form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
                submit.attr("style", "display: none !important");; // reset submit button text
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

4 jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js

```
(function ($) {
'use strict';

$.ajaxChimp = {
    responses: {
        'We have sent you a confirmation email'                                             : 0,
        'Please enter a valid email'                                                        : 1,
        'An email address must contain a single @'                                          : 2,
        'The domain portion of the email address is invalid (the portion after the @: )'    : 3,
        'The username portion of the email address is invalid (the portion before the @: )' : 4,
        'This email address looks fake or invalid. Please enter a real email address'       : 5
    },
    translations: {
        'en': null
    },
    init: function (selector, options) {
        $(selector).ajaxChimp(options);
    }
};

$.fn.ajaxChimp = function (options) {
    $(this).each(function(i, elem) {
        var form = $(elem);
        var email = form.find('input[type=email]');
        var label = form.find('.info');

        var settings = $.extend({
            'url': form.attr('action'),
            'language': 'en'
        }, options);

        var url = settings.url.replace('/post?', '/post-json?').concat('&c=?');

        form.attr('novalidate', 'true');
        email.attr('name', 'EMAIL');

        form.submit(function () {
            var msg;
            function successCallback(resp) {
                if (resp.result === 'success') {
                    msg = 'We have sent you a confirmation email';
                    label.removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
                    email.removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
                } else {
                    email.removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
                    label.removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
                    var index = -1;
                    try {
                        var parts = resp.msg.split(' - ', 2);
                        if (parts[1] === undefined) {
                            msg = resp.msg;
                        } else {
                            var i = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
                            if (i.toString() === parts[0]) {
                                index = parts[0];
                                msg = parts[1];
                            } else {
                                index = -1;
                                msg = resp.msg;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        index = -1;
                        msg = resp.msg;
                    }
                }

                // Translate and display message
                if (
                    settings.language !== 'en'
                    && $.ajaxChimp.responses[msg] !== undefined
                    && $.ajaxChimp.translations
                    && $.ajaxChimp.translations[settings.language]
                    && $.ajaxChimp.translations[settings.language][$.ajaxChimp.responses[msg]]
                ) {
                    msg = $.ajaxChimp.translations[settings.language][$.ajaxChimp.responses[msg]];
                }
                label.html(msg);

                label.show(2000);
                if (settings.callback) {
                    settings.callback(resp);
                }
            }

            var data = {};
            var dataArray = form.serializeArray();
            $.each(dataArray, function (index, item) {
                data[item.name] = item.value;
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: successCallback,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                error: function (resp, text) {
                    console.log('mailchimp ajax submit error: ' + text);
                }
            });

            // Translate and display submit message
            var submitMsg = 'Submitting...';
            if(
                settings.language !== 'en'
                && $.ajaxChimp.translations
                && $.ajaxChimp.translations[settings.language]
                && $.ajaxChimp.translations[settings.language]['submit']
            ) {
                submitMsg = $.ajaxChimp.translations[settings.language]['submit'];
            }
            label.html(submitMsg).show(2000);

            return false;
        });
    });
    return this;
};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: Включите отображение ошибок

Comment: `url: 'mail.php', ` замените на `url: 'contact_process.php'`
У вас javascript останавливает стандартное поведение формы и перенаправляет запрос путем POST на страницу mail.php .

Comment: Спасибо вам за овтет!
Поменяла url: 'mail.php', на url: 'contact_process.php'
ничего не изменилось. В чем еще может быть ошибка?

Comment: У вас `id` формы  - `contactForm`, а в `mail-script.js` прописана форма `#myForm`. Или поставьте `id` формы `myForm`, или напишите `#contactForm` вместо `#myForm` в файле `mail-script.js`